# Why doesn't my php function append JS to wp_head

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

This is the `javascript HTML` I wish to append to my WordPress `header.php` file, following this post I compiled the following code which does not work (note I am inserting this to my `functions.php` file on my Child theme)

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}

function my_custom_js() {
    echo '<script id="bw-highlighter-config">
(function(w, d, s, e, id) {
  w._bhparse = w._bhparse || [];
  function l() {
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    var n = d.createElement(s), x = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    n.id = id; n.async = true; n.src = '//bibles.org/linker/js/client.js';
    x.parentNode.insertBefore(n, x);
  }
  (w.attachEvent) ? w.attachEvent('on' + e, l) : w.addEventListener(e, l, false);
})(window, document, 'script', 'load', 'bw-highlighter-src');
</script> ';
}


// Add hook for front-end <head></head>
add_action('wp_head', 'my_custom_js');
```

Comment: The end of the `n.src` string is not defined at the place you want in the example you gave (because of the `//` in it, interpreted as a comment by PHP). You must escape your `'` in your JavaScript code, or use `"` instead for the strings in it.

Comment: Why aren't you enqueueing the script at the same time you enqueue the CSS?

Comment: @Jeremy that workerd, I used `"` for all string literals, including `on script load and bw-highlighter-src` but my website still does not accept the function, and is blank.

Comment: @Burgi Like this `wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', add_action('wp_head', 'my_custom_js');` ?

Comment: (1) There are multiple syntax errors (which is resulting in an error), (2) You should be enqueueing this in the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook, not `wp_head`

Comment: +1 for using `wp_enqueue_scripts` instead of `wp_head`. In the example we can see "fuI:nction" to create the function: is it a mistake in the copy/paste process? If it appears in your original code, it must be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @rnevius.

In your function `theme_enqueue_styles()` you should try something like this:

```
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() .'/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_scripts('js-name','/path/to/internal.js');
}
```

More information on the function is available on the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

Your JS also contains several typos.

Comment: Good info, but the OP doesn't want to enqueue an external JS file.

Comment: Changed the psuedo path to reference internal JS.

Comment: @rnevius I'll come up with a better solution on my drive home. I can't remember if you can call the custom function from within the enqueue

Comment: You can add the `echo` directly to the `theme_enqueue_styles()` function, or call the OP's original function from `theme_enqueue_styles()`